# Replace customers account creation fields [M2.3.3]

Tags: module, customer-attribute, magento2.3.3

I would replace two fields in customer account creation :

- First Name should become Account Number
- Name Prefix should become Company Name

And these two fields must appear in orders export...

[image: The 2 fields i want to replace :]

If you have any hints to help me..

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem

I've started with a free module which allow us to manipulate the customer's attributes, but it doesnt apply in StoreFront at the checkout Step.

This module is Clarion/Customer-Attribute and you can find it at https://marketplace.magento.com/clarion-customer-attribute.html

At this point i needed the labels to be renamed in checkout step too, the best solution i found was to modify them in mySql :

```
UPDATE eav_attribute SET frontend_label='Company Name' WHERE frontend_label = 'Name Prefix';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.021 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0 

UPDATE eav_attribute SET frontend_label='Account Number' WHERE frontend_label = 'First Name';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.021 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
```

Flush cache, setup:upgrade blablabla and it's working.